# Scale is not applied in e_scatter

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have this code:

```
library(echarts4r)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  EIXOX = 1:100,
  VAR1 = 200:101,
  VAR2 = 201:300,
  VAR3 = 301:400,
  VAR4 = 401:500
)

my_scale <- function(x) scales::rescale(x, to = c(5, 45))

df_1 |>
  e_chart(x = EIXOX, height = 250) |>
  e_scatter(serie = VAR1, legend = FALSE, scale = my_scale)
```

But the size of the points is the same, they do not change when the x axis advances. How to adjust this?

I need to keep y and x in their places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map a column on `size=`. However, that does not work when using the variable already mapped on `y` (or I miss something). Fro that reason I added a helper column with a different name:

```r
library(echarts4r)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  EIXOX = 1:100,
  VAR1 = 200:101,
  VAR2 = 201:300,
  VAR3 = 301:400,
  VAR4 = 401:500
)

my_scale <- function(x) scales::rescale(x, to = c(5, 45))

df_1 |>
  transform(VAR1_size = VAR1) |> 
  e_charts(EIXOX) |>
  e_scatter(VAR1, VAR1_size, legend = FALSE, scale = my_scale)
```

[image]